# Socket.IO Handle Ping Pong when sending a lot of data

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Can sending a lot of data cause a problem on socket io's ping pong system?

If the WebSocket Buffer is full, and sending data is slow, the client will not send a "pong" response to the server?
Will the server consider the client to be disconnected?